# Image not rendered in tab control runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a wpf application with multiple tab controls. I want to show some images of equations that are always available to the user when browsing through the tabs. The image shows in the design mode but does not show in run-time. I tried inserting the same image INSIDE on of the tab items and it renders just fine.

The image is saved in a file in the Resources and its build action is set to resource.

```html
<TabControl>
  <TabItem Header="Step 5">
    <my:Step5 Loaded="Step5_Loaded" />
  </TabItem>
  <TabItem Header="Step 6">
    <my:Step6 Loaded="Step6_Loaded" />
  </TabItem>
  <TabItem Header="Step 7">
    <my:Step7 Loaded="Step7_Loaded" />
  </TabItem>
</TabControl>
<Grid>

  <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14">
    My text
  </TextBlock>
  <Image Source="/DYN26;component/Resources/Equations/ca.gif/" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: For some reason, it renders when I set the 'stretch' property to none.

Comment: Does the image has a valid size? `TabControl` and `Grid` may have different measuring systems.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "/" after ".gif" in your Source so it looks like this:

```
<Image Source="/DYN26;component/Resources/Equations/ca.gif" />
```

.[file] is usually the end of a source link, if you've got a "/" after it, it will expect another location to drill down into, and if there is no text after the "/" then it means nothing.